# No route matches [PUT] "/users" on create action

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to create a registration page for my application. While creating a new user I am getting this error. Thanks a lot in advance !

routes. rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users



  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

new.html.erb

```
    <div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="login col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <%= form_for (@userInfo, :url => users_path, :method => 'post') do |f| %>
      <label>First Name</label><%= f.text_field(:first_name) %><br/><br/>
      <label>Last Name</label><%= f.text_field(:last_name) %><br/><br/>
      <label>Email</label><%= f.text_field(:email) %><br/><br/>
      <label>Password</label><%= f.text_field(:password) %><br/><br/>
      <label>Date of Birth</label><%= f.text_field(:dob) %><br/><br/>
      <label>Contact No.</label><%= f.text_field(:contactno) %><br/><br/>
      <%= f.submit('Register User') %>

    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

user_controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  layout 'HomeLayout'

  def new
      @userInfo = TblUserInformation.new
  end

  def create
    @userInfo = TblUserInformation.new(params[:user])
    @userInfo.save
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes` ? My gut tells me you should be using new_user_path or something of the like

Comment: Could you please output `rake routes` ?

Comment: users_path is likely the route for your index route. Try new_user_path

Comment: users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `rails routes` show you :
`POST /users(.:format) users#create new_user`
You must use `new_user_path` in the form_for url attribute.